# The probability that two balls with the label-sum $4$ are picked

Tags: probability

I am looking at the following:

A lottery wheel contains five red, blue and yellow balls. For each color the balls are labeled with the numbers $ 1,2,3,4 $ and $ 5 $. A good fairy draws from the lottery wheel two successive balls. A ball which has already been drawn is not moved into the drum.

$$$$

To calculate the probability that two balls with the label-sum $4$ are picked do we have to calculate the probability $$P((\text{ Ball with label } 1) \cap (\text{ Ball with label } 3))+P((\text{ Ball with label } 3) \cap (\text{ Ball with label } 1))+P((\text{ Ball with label } 2) \cap (\text{ Ball with label } 2))$$ ?

We have that $P((\text{ Ball with label } 1) \cap (\text{ Ball with label } 3))=\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{14}$, $P((\text{ Ball with label } 3) \cap (\text{ Ball with label } 1))=\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{14}$ and $P((\text{ Ball with label } 2) \cap (\text{ Ball with label } 2))=\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{2}{14}$, or not?

Therefore we get $$P(\text{ two balls with the label-sum } 4 \text{ are picked })=\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{14}+\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{14}+\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{2}{14}$$

Is that correct?

Comment: depends on if order is important.

Comment: What I did is for the case that the order is important, right? Would it be correct? If the order is not important would it be as follows $$P((\text{ Ball with label } 1) \cup (\text{ Ball with label } 3))+P((\text{ Ball with label } 2) \cup (\text{ Ball with label } 2))=\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{3}{14}+\frac{3}{15}\cdot \frac{2}{14}$$ ? @RoddyMacPhee

Comment: I'm not a probability expert , but that's what came to mind, when I was thinking about what he question was asking.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. If you are not replacing the first ball, there are 210 total possible ways to draw 2 balls, of which 24 add up to 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning in the question is correct, however your continued analysis in the comment is not.

In this case, order is unimportant because the questions asks for the probability that the sum of the labels on the two balls is $4$. Since addition is commutative, order is irrelevant.

There are two ways you can choose to break this down:

1. I choose two balls labeled 1 and 3, or I choose two balls labeled 2.

Using this approach, **you must consider the fact that there are two ways for the first clause to occur**, resulting in an answer of: $2\cdot\frac{3}{15}\cdot\frac{3}{14} + 1\cdot\frac{3}{15}\frac{2}{14}$

2. I choose a ball labeled 1 and then a ball labeled 3, or I choose a ball labeled 3 and then a ball labeled 1, or I choose a ball labeled 2 and then a ball labeled 2.

Using this approach, you have explicitly stated the order of drawing balls, so there is only one way for each case to occur. Your answer is: $1\cdot\frac{3}{15}\cdot\frac{3}{14} + 1\cdot\frac{3}{15}\cdot\frac{3}{14} + 1\cdot\frac{3}{15}\frac{2}{14}$

Comment: I got it!! Thank you so much!! :-) Could you maybe take also a look at my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348705/are-the-events-independent